# Android Deep link for friendly URLs

Tags: android, android-studio, url, android-manifest, android-deep-link

How would the **deep link** in the *manifest* be to open an *activity* with this link

https://myapp.domain.com/#/view/abc

where only **abc** is the *argument* that changes and is the one that I need the app to take as a *parameter* .

I have tried this but it did not work

```
            <data
                android:host="myapp.domain.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/#/view"
                android:scheme="https" />
            <data
                android:host="myapp.domain.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/#/view"
                android:scheme="http" />
            <data
                android:host="myapp.domain.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/#/view"
                android:scheme="app" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this inside Activity Tag in Manifest file

```
<intent-filter android:label="Example">
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            
      <data android:scheme="https"
            android:host="myapp.domain.com"
            android:pathPrefix="/#" />
            <!-- note that the leading "/" is required for pathPrefix-->
</intent-filter>
```

Inside Activity.java

```
 Uri uri = getIntent().getData();
 
 if(uri != null){
      List<String> segments = uri.getPathSegments();
      Log.e(TAG, "onCreate: "+segments );
      Log.e(TAG, "onCreate: "+segments.get((segments.size()-1)) );
 }
```

Comment: Does not work, when click on link android only shows up open with chrome but not my app :(

Answer (score 0):

After hard work I used this:

```
<data android:scheme="https"
        android:host="myapp.domain.com"
        android:pathPrefix="/" />
```

And in my Activity:

```
 String id = data.toString().replaceAll(".*/", "");
```

NOTE: I **couldn't** use *uri.getPathSegments();* because it returns me empty list.